# NSExpression Subquery usage

Tags: ios, swift

Swift 3 introduced a new [NSExpresion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsexpression#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-SW22) type [Subquery expression](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsexpression/1411651-init). I tried to use it in Playground but could not get it to work.

First I created a class in Sources folder in MyPlayground:

```
// example classes
public class Person {
  public let name: String
  public let birthYear: Int

  init(name pName: String, birthYear year : Int) {
    name = pName
    birthYear = year
  }
}

public class Parent: Person {
  public var children: [Person] = [Person]()
  override init(name pName: String, birthYear year : Int) {
    super.init(name: pName, birthYear: year)
  }
}

public class TestSubquery {
  // Method to get a Parent
  public class func getParent() -> Parent {
    let p = Parent(name: "Bob", birthYear: 1997)
    let c = Person(name: "Tonny", birthYear: 2010)
    p.children.append(c)
    return p
  }
}
```

In MyPlayground, the collection expression is created as e1 (I tried both aggregate and format expression, all are collection expression but failed in late part):

```
let p = TestSubquery.getParent()
print("\(p.children.count)") // 1
let e1 = NSExpression(forAggregate: p.children)
// let e1 = NSExpressoin(format: "%@", p.children)
print("e1: \(e1)")
//e1: {MyPlayground_Sources.Person}
```

Then a subquery expression as e2 is created:

```
let e2 = NSExpression(forSubquery: e1, usingIteratorVariable: "x", predicate: "$x.birthYear > 0")
print("\(e2)")
// SUBQUERY({MyPlayground_Sources.Person}, $x, $x.birthYear > 0)
```

Finally when I tried to get result from expression, error occurred:

```
let expValue = e2.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil)
// Error
```

The error message is as follows:

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x6080000547f0 of class 'MyPlayground_Sources.Person' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[MyPlayground_Sources.Person expressionValueWithObject:context:]
```

It looks like key-value cannot be found. I am not sure what is wrong to build Subquery expression.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days struggling, I think I got a solution!

First, the class in the collection, for example `Person` in an array, has to be inherited from `NSObject`.

```
public class Person : NSObject {
```

Secondly, according to Apple's [Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsexpression/1411651-init)

[image]

That is, the third parameter should be `NSPredicate` type (even though `String` is of `Any`?). The updated `e2` should be like:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "$x.birthYear > 0")
let e2 = NSExpression(forSubquery: e1, usingIteratorVariable: "x", predicate: predicate)
let expValue = e2.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil)
```

With those changes, the Subquery expression works like charm.